# Provider.ValidateUser not true if not approved

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Must I use user.isapproved instead of the a of the above if the user is registered but not approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Account approval is a separate concept from being a valid user, so you have to check both if you're using the approval mechanism.